# how to cast in MySQL stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, casting

Trying to create the following routine in MySQL Workbench yields a "This object's DDL statement contains syntax errors. Are you sure you want to apply the DDL statement unchanged?":

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `dbName`.`testFunc` ()
BEGIN
SET i = CAST(100 AS DOUBLE);
END
```

Any ideas?

This does the same thing:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `rateGenius`.`testFunc` ()
BEGIN

SET i = CONVERT(100, DOUBLE);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare i in your stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `rateGenius`.`testFunc` ()
BEGIN

DECLARE i DOUBLE
SET i = 100.0;

END
```

Not sure what you're actually trying to do with this stored proc though. Your `CAST/CONVERT` is unecessary in this case but your syntax for those functions is in fact correct.